# Pegar todos os nomes e colocar virgula para separa-los

Tags: php

Quando obtenho os nomes e adiciono para uma variável, eu não posso separa-las com virgula normalmente.

- tem que ser por virgula e ponto no final
- não posso colocar cada nome em quebra de linha usando

É difícil explicar, porem vai um exemplo:

```
while ($listintegrantes = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
        $integrantes = "$integrantes" . $listintegrantes['nome'] . ",";
}
```

ou seja, isso vai mostrar assim:

> john, Cyrax, john2,

Porem eu quero que fique:

> john, Cyrax e john2.

Como isso é possível fazer isso?

-SOLUÇÃO

Segue a resolução do problema postado acima, todas as resoluções são corretas, adaptei ao meu problema para que me retorne meu objetivo correto.

```
        $query1 = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql1);
        $integrantes = "";
        $i = mysqli_num_rows($query1);
        $x = 1;
        while ($listintegrantes = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
            $integrantes = $integrantes . $listintegrantes['nome'];
            if ($x < $i - 1) {//antes do penultimo
                $integrantes = $integrantes . ", ";
            }elseif($x == $i-1){//penultimo
                $integrantes = $integrantes . " e ";
            }elseif($x == $i){//ultimo
                $integrantes = $integrantes . ".";
            }
            $x++;
        }
```

segue abaixo o feedback do algoritmo acima:
*Cyrax, John, Serana e Smigol.*

quando há somente um registro de integrante:
*Serana.*

Comment: Você pode iterar a variável integrantes de trás pra frente e quando achar a vírgula, trocar por `.` e continuar, quando achar a penúltima vírgula, trocar por `e`.

Comment: Pode usar um `rtrim($integrantes, ',')` no final do while e depois só concatenar um ponto no final. Uma ideia só.

Comment: Removi a solução de sua pergunta, o lugar delas é nas respostas.

Comment: É melhor criar uma resposta com a sua solução, o espaço da pergunta é so para pergunta :P. O site funciona diferente de um fórum veja as diferenças na [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) é um guia rapido :)

Comment: Sua solução parece ter sido adaptada com base na resposta do @Jorge B., pode marcar a resposta dele como a correta. Os votos não influenciam na opção de escolha.

Comment: A sim, obrigado, eu estou me adaptando nesse site ainda, nem sei como é escolher a resposta ainda .... rs, porem verei aqui. acredito que é o verde.

Comment: Basta escolher a resposta que se adequar melhor ao seu caso, não tem mistério rs. Dê uma olhada no help depois pra tirar qualquer dúvida. E problemas podem ser resolvidos no [*Meta*](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```
$sinal = ", ";
$size = mysqli_num_rows($query1);
$i = 1;
while ($listintegrantes = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) 
{
    if($i == $size-1) 
        $sinal = " e ";
    elseif($i == $size) 
        $sinal = ".";

    $integrantes .= $listintegrantes['nome'] . $sinal;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: ele retornou
John1, Cyrax, john2,

Comment: @MuriloManzoliCOLLAPSE fiz uma alteração testa agora

Comment: retornou
John1 e Cyrax e John2.

Comment: Eu testei e aqui deu direito. Copia todo o código que pus aqui.

Comment: vou dar uma mechida no codigo, logo postarei a solução baseada na sua, muito bom ! obrigado ^^ se caso quiser continuar a editar, tranquilo ^^

Answer (score 9):

Outra forma seria simpelsmente retirando o último elemento da array, usar implode para colocar as virgulas se houver nome suficiente para a separação e depois recolocar o último elemento de volta.

```
    function names( array $names )
    {
        $_names = array_pop( $names );

        if( count( $names ) > 0 )
        return implode( ', ' , $names ) . ' e ' . $_names;

        return 'só ' . $_names;
    }

    // output: só eu
    echo names( ['eu'] );

    // output: eu e tu
    echo names( ['eu' , 'tu' ] );

    // output: eu, tu e ele
    echo names( ['eu' , 'tu' , 'ele' ] );
```

Comment: +1 nem me passou pela cabeça.

Comment: vou dar uma olhada, logo posto a solução correta, muito obrigado !

Comment: Não há uma 'solução correta', basta ver as tantas respostas... Só precisa escolher a solução mais adaptável ao que precisa. Qualquer duvida basta comentar.

Answer (score 7):

Outra forma de fazer é usar a lógica contraria, concatenar a string com `e`(sim tem espaços) e no final usar [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) para substituir todos os `e` por `,` exceto o último, esse controle é feito com o quarto parâmetro que é o numero de substituições.

No exemplo de um array com cinco elementos se tornará uma string com quatro `e`, agora basta saber o número de substituições feitas que é o total de elementos menos dois que é 3.

Exemplo 1

```
$itens = 1;
while ($listintegrantes = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
       $integrantes = "$integrantes" . $listintegrantes['nome'] . " e ";
       $itens++;
}

$str = preg_replace('/ e /', ', ', $integrantes, $itens - 2);
```

[Exemplo 2 ideon](http://ideone.com/E60kTA)

```
$arr = array('john', 'Cyrax', 'john', 'Sonia', 'Sector');
$str = implode(' e ', $arr);
$itens = count($arr);
$str_formatada = preg_replace('/ e /', ', ', $str, count($arr)-2);
echo $str_formatada;

saida : john, Cyrax, john, Sonia e Sector
```

Answer (score 4):

Poderia ser assim:

```
while ($listintegrantes = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
    $integrantes = "$integrantes" . $listintegrantes['nome'] . ",";
}

$integrantes = rtrim($integrantes, ',') . '.';
```

Comment: falta o " e " no penúltimo.

Comment: Boa, não tinha me atentado a isso.

Answer (score 4):

Outra solução possível obter a posição da última ocorrência do caractere na string **[strrpos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strrpos.php)** e substituir **[substr_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr-replace.php)**, exemplo:

```
$arr = array('john', 'Cyrax', 'john', 'Sonia', 'Sector');
$str = implode(', ',$arr);
$str = substr_replace($str, ' e', strrpos($str,','), 1);
echo $str;
```

**[Exemplo Ideone](http://ideone.com/ARMOti)**

Answer (score -2):

```
            $itens = 0;
            $integrantes ="";
            foreach($data->data as $chave => $users){     
            $itens++;
                if( $itens <= 1){
                    $integrantes = "$integrantes" . $users->audit;
                    $str = $integrantes;
                }elseif($itens > 1){
                    $integrantes = "$integrantes" . " e ". $users->audit;
                    $str = ltrim(preg_replace('/ e /', ', ', $integrantes, $itens - 2),',');
                }
            }
```