# Laço de Repetição

Tags: php

Como insiro uma `","` entre os itens no `While` e no último item ponho um `"e"` mais um `"."`.
Lembrando que meu array irá carregar de acordo com os dados no banco.

Preciso que ele seja escrito assim:

`Pera`, `Uva`, `Melao` e `Morango`.

```
vetor = new Array ("Pera", "Uva", "Melao", "Morango");
```

Comment: Parece a mesma lógica dessa [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60261/91)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pelo teu exemplo fico com a sensação que estás a usar JavaScript... pois falta-te `$` nas variáveis e em JavaScript usa-se `new Array()`. No PHP usa-se só `array()`. Juntei ambas as soluções.

## PHP

Podes tirar o ultimo elemento, juntar os outros com `,` e depois colocar de volta com concatenação simples.

```
$vetor = array("Pera", "Uva", "Melao", "Morango");
$ultimo = array_pop($vetor);
$string = implode(', ', $vetor);
$string.= " e {$ultimo}.";
```

#### Exemplo: https://ideone.com/sjfjX2

---

## JavaScript

```
var vetor = new Array("Pera", "Uva", "Melao", "Morango");
var ultimo = vetor.pop();
var string = vetor.join(', ');
string += ' e ' + ultimo + '.';
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lj5vktd7/

Comment: eu tentei editar, mas não estou conseguindo. Faltou um espaço no `','` e no `'e '.$ultimo`.'.'; gerando `Pera,Uva,Melaoe Morango.`

Comment: Sugiro usar `$string.= " e {$ultimo}.";`

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert obrigado. Juntei a tua sugestão! Tinha colocado certo no Ideone mas aqui ainda faltava o espaço.

Answer (score 3):

para inserir uma `,` entre os elementos utilize um `implode` desta forma:

```
$separado = implode(",", $vetor);
```

encontrar a ultima virgula:

```
$pos = strripos($separado, ',');
```

colocar o `e`:

```
$string = substr_replace($separado, ' e ', $pos, 1);
```

colocar um ponto ao final:

```
$string .= '.';
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/2JUHpV)

Answer (score 1):

Espero ajudar com a minha resposta, pois tentei encontrar outra forma de o fazer.
Aqui vai...

```
<?php

$vetor = array("Pera", "Uva", "Melao", "Morango");

$final = $vetor[0];

for ($i = 1; $i < count($vetor) - 1; $i++)
{
    $final.= ', '.$vetor[$i];
}

$final.= ' e '.end($vetor).'.';

echo $final;
```

Comment: tirando o fato de que você esta inserindo duas vezes `Morango` esta ok. altere para `count($vetor) - 1`, que resolve.

Comment: Done... Obrigado @Guilherme Lautert, foi falta de atenção!