# como separar os valores do array por "," e "e"

Tags: php

Olá tenho um array e preciso printar ele na tela separado por , e e
ex..

```
<select name="quitacao[um]"class="large m-wrap" data-trigger="hover"  required="" > 
<select name="quitacao[dois]"class="large m-wrap" data-trigger="hover" required="" >
```

e assim vai

então vou ter um array quitacao na proxima tela

se eu fizer isso

```
implode(",",$quitacao);
```

vou conseguir separar tudo por virgula mas eu preciso que o ultimo fica com E

ex.. 
Janeiro, Fevereiro, Março E Novembro

Comment: [Pegar todos os nomes e colocar virgula para separa-los](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60261/91)

Answer (score 3):

Pegue todos os elementos do array até o penúltimo deles e concatene-os com uma vírgula; então concatene o último com um "e":

```
function concatena($meses)
{
    $string  = implode(', ', array_slice($meses, 0, -1));
    $string .= ' e ' . $meses[count($meses)-1];

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Rodrigo

Comment: Nesse caso, creio que sua resposta seja melhor em casos onde o `array` original não possa ser modificado. Porque na resposta do @DanielOmine, o `array` perderia o último elemento por causa do `array_pop`, que trabalha na referência do `array`, ao invés de retornar o `array`;

Comment: verdade. Bem observado @WallaceMaxters. Fiz uma edição adicionando uma dica simples para esse caso onde necessitar usar o array inteiro.

Answer (score 3):

```
$arr = ['janeiro', 'fevereiro', 'março', 'abril', 'maio'];
$l = array_pop($arr);
echo implode( ', ', $arr ) . ' e ' . $l;
```

A função `array_pop()` remove o último elemento do array e retorna o seu valor.

A variável `$l` recebe o valor, para então poder usá-lo na concatenação.

Para o caso de precisar usar o array em sua forma original, basta retornar o valor removido pela função `array_pop()`.

```
$arr[] = $l;
```

Comment: Obrigado daniel

Comment: Na verdade, se você colocar isso tudo dentro de uma função, `array_pop` só trabalhará na variável do `array` no contexto da função (claro, se você declarar o parâmetro sem a referência).

Comment: o que isso tem a ver? rsrs